# How to move an object at 2/3px per second(paint)

Tags: java

I would like to make two classes. One (class Mover) is changing the fields that other(class Window) is using to repaint something every 1/30 seconds.

But the pace of the movement should be less or equal to 20 pixels per second.

But even `20/30 == 0` so i cannot move an object by 2/3 pixels even if I use a double then I should cast it and it will be at least 30px/s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep your position in floating point and just round it when you need to draw it. The important difference to the approach you mentioned is that you do not round the velocity, but round the actual position.